# How to get Firefox to only load images from trusted origins

Tags: firefox, internet, security, customization, configure

As you can see by the name, I am paranoid, and I realise that I can get something malicious on my machine through looking at an image. I have disabled my browser's cache, but this still only limits the threat as the malicious stuff now would just go into memory. So to increase my level of security, but not completely destroy usability, how would I go about configuring Firefox so that it will only load images from trusted sources?

So what I mean is so that I can tell it to block all images (and not load them into memory or anything), but give it a list of exceptions that I can easily add to, and if possible, have something that I can just select like with NoScript to automatically add a site to the whitelist while I am on that site, and have to ability to say that I want to allow a site to show me images which is not the actual site I am on, but one from which that site is loading images from.
So for it to basically work like NoScript does, except have images and their sources rather than scripts.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @DKBose: Can you add that as an answer please with installation instructions etc.

Comment: **ParanoidPanda:** answer it yourself and make it a community wiki  if **@DKBose** doesn't want to answer it.  Even kinda off-topic, it's still a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [uMatrix browser extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/umatrix/):

[image]

Its usage is explained in the [documentation here](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

From [DK Bose's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650240/how-to-get-firefox-to-only-load-images-from-trusted-origins#comment933678_650240):

> You can esily do so using [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/). [The wiki](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki) is pretty explanatory.